# ggplot2 geom_point size breaks (categories) for a continuous variable

Tags: r, ggplot2

I'm trying to create a map with two variables where one is represented by polygon colors (choropleth fill) and the other is represented by bubble size at the centroid of each polygon. To make it concrete, let's consider `nc` data's two variables `AREA` and `BIR74` where `AREA` fills the polygon and `BIR74` is represented by size. To make it as similar as my actual case, I created a few NA values for `BIR74` variable.

```
library(tidyverse)
library(sf)
    nc <- sf::st_read(system.file("shape/nc.shp", package="sf")) 
    nc_centroids <- data.frame(nc %>% st_centroid() %>% st_coordinates())
    nc <- nc %>% bind_cols(nc, nc_centroids) %>% mutate(BIR74 = replace(BIR74, AREA < 0.08, NA))
```

Now, I hope to create a custom break for `BIR74` so that the bubble size is either "big" or "small", but even after supplying `scale_size_continuous(breaks = c(1000, 20000))`, the bubble size on the map seems to be continuous. For instance, see the red circle area in the map, which show at least three different circle sizes.

Here's what I've tried.

```
ggplot(nc) + geom_sf(aes(fill = AREA), colour = "white") + 
  geom_point(aes( x = X, y = Y, size = BIR74)) +
  scale_size_continuous(breaks = c(1000, 20000))
```

I could potentially translate the `BIR74` variable to character/factor but in this case I couldn't prevent the NA values show up on the map, which I don't want. Any comments would be appreciated!

[image]

Comment: I cannot reproduce this - I get two bubbles, just as you want.[see here](https://i.imgur.com/6IOs4YU.png)

Comment: P.S. when marking code inline in markdown, you can simply use a single tick `. Use three ticks ``` for an entire code chunk.

Comment: @Tjebo Thanks for the comment and the picture in the link. I also posted a plot based on the reproducible example and it looks quite different from yours... Especially the area in the red circle has at least three different bubble sizes...

Comment: Ah, sorry, I did not get that. Let me have a look

Comment: No worries! Thanks! Also, the legend in your plot looks different from mine as well. I'm curious if it's my computer's problem.

Comment: it's probably not a matter of your computer, just of your local settings. If I can recommend anything, then to use the `reprex` package which integrates really nicely with RStudio. It will always run your code in a virgin environment

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Scale breaks do not change how your data is displayed. Also setting the limits has not resulted in a change.

Therefore, transform your data first, and then plot the different sizes.

```r
library(tidyverse)
library(sf)

nc <- sf::st_read(system.file("shape/nc.shp", package="sf")) 

nc_centroids <- data.frame(nc %>% st_centroid() %>% st_coordinates())


nc2 <- 
  nc %>% 
  bind_cols(nc, nc_centroids) %>% 
  mutate(BIR74 = replace(BIR74, AREA < 0.08, NA),
         BIR74 = if_else(BIR74 < 10000, 1, 2)) %>%
  drop_na("BIR74") # this is not necessary, but it makes it visually clearer where you have missing values

ggplot(nc2) + 
  geom_sf(aes(fill = AREA), colour = "white") + 
  geom_point(aes( x = X, y = Y, size = BIR74)) +
  scale_size_continuous(breaks = 1:2)
```

[image]

<sup>Created on 2020-04-26 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v0.3.0)</sup>